# ServiceMix + Spring + CXF + Aegis = NullPointerException

Tags: spring, osgi, cxf, apache-servicemix, aegis

I'm trying to create a web service in ServiceMix, based on Spring and CXF with Aegis databinding. This service run as war in Tomcat without problems, but when i deploy it in ServiceMix i get a NullPointerException.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:309)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo$1.compare(BeanTypeInfo.java:308)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1270)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1282)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1281)
    at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1281)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1210)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.initializeProperties(BeanTypeInfo.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.aegis.type.basic.BeanTypeInfo.<init>(BeanTypeInfo.java:75)
```

My Spring beans are:

```
<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.company.ServiceSEI" />
    <property name="address" value="${ws.url}" />
    <property name="dataBinding" ref="aegisBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="aegisBean" class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisDatabinding"
    scope="prototype" />
```

Also i declare in the MANIFEST.MF:

```
<Import-Package>
    META-INF.cxf,
    META-INF.cxf.osgi,
    org.apache.cxf,
    org.apache.cxf.binding,
    org.apache.cxf.ws.security,
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws,
    org.apache.cxf.aegis,
    org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding,
    org.apache.cxf.aegis.type,
    org.springframework.beans.factory.config,
</Import-Package>
```

I can't find a solution to this problem, if a use JAXB there is no problem, but i need to use Aegis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known bug and seems to be open right this moment. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3613